# HDIV INVALID_PARAMETER_NAME error with Spring Tag form

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, hdiv

I am using a Spring Tag form element in which there are 3 parameters.

```
<sf:form class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="doCheck" id="checkForm" action="${url}" htmlEscape="true">
<div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label>Email : <span class="redStar">*</span></label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control user inputIconPos" id="inputEmail3" 
                            placeholder="Email Address"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
//2 more fields
</sf:form>
```

I am using Spring MVC version **4.1.7** and HDIV version **2.1.11**. And the error logged is

```
21:08:40.386 [http-bio-8100-exec-4] INFO  org.hdiv.logs.Logger - INVALID_PARAMETER_NAME;/check_submit.html;email;null;;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;anonymous;
21:08:40.386 [http-bio-8100-exec-4] DEBUG o.hdiv.filter.ValidatorHelperRequest - Validation Error Detected: Parameter [email] does not exist in the state for action [/check_submit.html]
```

HDIV Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:hdiv="http://www.hdiv.org/schema/hdiv"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.hdiv.org/schema/hdiv http://www.hdiv.org/schema/hdiv/hdiv.xsd">
<hdiv:config excludedExtensions="css,png,gif,jpg,jpeg,bmp,ico,js"  strategy="cipher" randomName="true" errorPage="/error.html" reuseExistingPageInAjaxRequest="true">
    <hdiv:sessionExpired loginPage="/login.html" homePage="/home.html"/>
    <hdiv:startPages>/adminlogin.html,/home.html</hdiv:startPages>
</hdiv:config>
<hdiv:validation id="safeText">
    <hdiv:acceptedPattern><![CDATA[^[a-zA-Z0-9@.\-_]*$]]>  </hdiv:acceptedPattern>
</hdiv:validation>
<hdiv:editableValidations registerDefaults="true">
    <hdiv:validationRule url=".*" enableDefaults="true">safeText</hdiv:validationRule>
</hdiv:editableValidations>
</beans>
```

I don't want to exclude these parameters from validation.
I would like to know how can configure HDIV so that these parameters are validated and not skipped.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show your entire hdiv configuration ?

Comment: Hi @smoggers - Done adding the hdiv config in edits

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Spring form tag to create form fields:

```
<form:input path="email" type="email" ... />
```

Gotzon

Comment: Tried that as well with by providing a command attribute in form with form:input elements inside and  @ModelAttribute in Controller. I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below configuration in your hdiv config to skip validation on the parameter -

```
<hdiv:paramsWithoutValidation>
      <hdiv:mapping url=".*" parameters="email"/>
</hdiv:paramsWithoutValidation>
```

In `url` you can give `"/check_submit.html"` if you want this on this particular page.